# Ext JS 4 - how to get a specific tab and insert content (view)

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, tabs, components

What is the current MVC/Ext 4 JS recommended method of getting a reference to a specific tab in a tab panel (that is inside a view) and setting it's content (from a controller)?

I have seen conflicting information, for example, to use Ext.get, Ext.getCmp, getComponent(), and several other examples.

I can get the view, for example, by using "getMyView()". But now, how do I get the tab inside the tab panel that view?  Then, I need to set that tab's content.   (if this is the recommended method)

Ultimately I am trying to create another controller and view (for example a customer list) and insert that in to the tab panel.  So I am thinking get the reference to the tab panel content, then set the 'renderTo' of my view to that.  Does that make sense?